# Can I add the developer token dynamically in the code when using google adwords api instead of writing it in the auth.ini file?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I'm developing a website that deals with different adwords account and each account has his own developer token , so is there any way to add the developer token in the same way as adding the client id using    `$user->SetClientCustomerId($id);`

Comment: Why don't you try it, see what results you get and then post your attempt and whatever errors or debugging output you have?  The more you can provide an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve the better our comments will be.

Comment: Actually I found another way to solve it. I store the developer token of each account in the database and each time I will delete the ini file and then create it with the new developer token

Comment: Just as a FYI, as far as I know you are not supposed to use other people's developer tokens as they are being used to enforce rate limits for the API.

Comment: @dorian so can I use my developer token to get data of other accounts if I have the client id ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using an OAuth access token that gives you access to these accounts, then absolutely. The developer token is solely used to identify a given request with a specific developer/company, it doesn't have any authorization semantics in the way of determining whether you are allowed to access a given Adwords account.

Comment: @dorian Great Thank you.
I just posted a new question if you can help me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269995/retrieving-all-campaign-information-from-google-adwords-api-as-an-array